# How to resolve "No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.BsonUndefined] to type [java.lang.String] " only when Docs Count > 100

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, full-text-search, spring-data-mongodb

I am using mongo db map reduce functionality for my requirement to process textual data.

I am using the below map, reduce and finalize functions for my requirement. I am also using Spring Data Mongo DB to execute the mapreduce operation.

The spring data mongo db code for the mapreduce functionality is executed on startup of the app by using the Spring Boot Application's, CommandLineRunner. The app is standalone non-web application.

The **Map function** I use is as below,

```
 function() {
    var document = this;
    var stopwords = ["the","be","to","of","and","a","in"];
    for(var prop in document) {
      if(prop === "_id" || typeof document[prop] !== 'string') {
        continue
      }
      (document[prop]).split(" ").forEach(
        function(word){
          var cleanedWord = word.replace(/[;,.]/g,"")
          if(
            stopwords.indexOf(cleanedWord) > -1 ||
            !(isNaN(parseInt(cleanedWord))) ||
            !(isNaN(parseFloat(cleanedWord)))
          ) {
            return
          }
          var value={
                userId:document.userId,
                docId:document._id
          }
          emit(cleanedWord,value)
        }
      ) 
    }
  }
```

**The reduce function is:**

```
function(k,v){
   var output={'documents':[] };
   v.forEach(
      function(vs){
          var values = { 'userId': '', 'docIdStr': []};
         var checkExisting = false;

         output.documents.forEach(
               function(test){
                          if (test.userId ===vs.userId)
                             {
                                if(!(test.docIdStr.indexOf(vs.docId) > -1))
                                  {
                                    test.docIdStr.push(vs.docId);
                                  }
                                 checkExisting =true;
                             }
               }
         )
        if(!checkExisting)
                {
                    values.userId=vs.userId ;
                    values.docIdStr.push(vs.docId);
                    output.documents.push(values);
                }
      }

     )
     return output
  }
```

**Finalize function**

```
function(key,reducedValue){

        var finalValue = {documents:[]}
        if(reducedValue.documents) {
          finalValue.documents = reducedValue.documents.filter(
            function(item,pos,self){
              var loc = -1;
              for(var i=0;i<self.length;i++){
                if(self[i].valueOf() === item.valueOf()){
                  loc = i;
                  break
                }
              }
              return loc === pos;
              }
          );
        } else {

              if (!reducedValue.documents)
                     {
                  var values = { 'userId': '', 'docIdStr': []};

                       values.userId=reducedValue.userId ;
                       values.docIdStr.push(reducedValue.docId.str);
                      finalValue.documents.push(values)
                     }

              else{
          finalValue.documents =reducedValue.documents 
              }
        }

        return finalValue
      }
```

The **document structure in Source Collection** is as below,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590af61465b4effc50b20961"),
    "userId" : "user9",
    "year" : 2016,
    "title" : "reprehenderit",
    "content" : "laborum ea consectetur fugiat duis velit consequat voluptate cillum culpa sit consectetur cillum"
}
```

The sample **document structure in target collection** which I am trying to populate is as below. This is an access control list for a word mapping to user and doc list.

```
{
    "_id" : "Lorem",
    "value" : {
        "documents" : [ 
            {
                "userId" : "user65",
                "docIdStr" : [
                    ObjectId("590af61465b4effc50b20967"), 
                    ObjectId("590af61465b4effc50b20995"), 
                    ObjectId("590af61465b4effc50b209bd")
                            ]
            }
       ]
}
```

The **spring data mongodb Code** fragment I use is as below,

```
mongoOperations.mapReduce
        (

             "CustomCollection",
             "classpath:map.js", 
             "classpath:reduce.js",
             new MapReduceOptions()
                .finalizeFunction("classpath:finalize.js")
                .outputCollection("CustomOutput"),
                CustomOutput.class
        );
```

I am seeing exception in the logs when the count of docs in mongo source collection exceeds 100. With docs <=100 it works fine without exceptions.

Most of the fields in the populated collection are having undefined as the value of the fields.

The exception stacktrace , I get is as below.

```
2017-05-04 15:35:10.154 ERROR 2556 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:785) ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    at com.demo.examples.MongoMapReduceApplication.main(MongoMapReduceApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.BsonUndefined] to type [java.lang.String]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:324) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:206) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:187) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:823) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1199) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:79) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1145) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:871) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:284) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:232) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:906) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1195) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:79) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1145) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:871) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:284) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:232) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1197) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:79) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1145) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:871) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:284) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:232) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:192) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:188) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:79) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2297) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.mapReduce(MongoTemplate.java:1400) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.mapReduce(MongoTemplate.java:1362) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.demo.examples.service.MapReduceService.populateCollection(MapReduceService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.demo.examples.MongoMapReduceApplication.run(MongoMapReduceApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:801) ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    ... 4 common frames omitted

2017-05-04 15:35:10.156  INFO 2556 --- [main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@235045: startup date [Thu May 04 15:35:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-04 15:35:10.158  INFO 2556 --- [main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-05-04 15:35:10.160  INFO 2556 --- [main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:148}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

Can someone help in identifying the cause of the issue and resolving it.